# i can't see nodes

Tags: materials, node-editor, object-mode

[image]

as you can see I have opened node editor panel and I also clicked new but I can't see nodes

Answer (score 2):

The *Use nodes* checkbox at the bottom of the node editor is unchecked so material isn't used.